# How to mock Chrome Extension APIs in a React app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension which loads a React app via a content script. This is working but now I also want to import the app into a standalone React app (ideally NextJS) for a better developer experience.

When I import the component I get errors where I've used the Chrome Extension APIs eg

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendMessage')

How can I get around this? Ideally id mock the chrome object in the standalone React app rather than check if chrome.runtime exists in the UI components. I dont mind if the stand alone React app uses a hacky approach as its just for developing locally.

```
// content script: 
const popupElem = document.createElement("iframe");
  popupElem.setAttribute(
    "style",
    `
    position: fixed;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100vh;
    border: none;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    `
  );
popupElem.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("./src/popup.html");
document.body.append(popupElem);


// popup.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  <script type="module" src="./popup-react.tsx"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root">
  </div>
</body>
</html>


// popup-react.tsx
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import Popup from "./Popup";

const root = document.getElementById("root")!;

ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Popup />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// Popup.tsx
export defualt function Popup() {
  function handleClick() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: 'Howdy' });
  }
 return <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</div>
}
```